# Custom Index with Xindy and Imakeidx

Tags: imakeidx, xindy

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434953/xindy-fails-to-sort-umlauts-in-imakeidx?noredirect=1#comment1091026_434953), we addressed the issue of proper sorting in an automated author name index. It worked fine until I merged the code with these two redefinitions made by Enrico in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435021/smallcaps-for-page-number-of-index-entries-in-roman-style-imakeidx/435029#435029) in order to have the roman pagenumber in the index printed in smallcaps:

```
\newcommand{\scindex}[2][]{\index[#1]{#2|textsc}}   % NEW Enrico

    \DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%      
      \usebibmacro{index:name}
        {\scindex[nomi]}   %NEW Enrico
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
```

ATM I'm running:

- XeLateX
- Biber on the aux
- Xindy on nomi.idx
- XeLaTeX again

And I got no index.

If I remove the Enrico's redefinition for the smallcaps issue, it works again.

Is there a way to make these two things stay together?

This is my MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@book{Dull,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {Mark Dull},
    Publisher = {Amazon KDP},
    Title = {Hello world},
    Year = {1999}}

@book{Dol2,
    Address = {Moskwa},
    Author = {Philip Döllinger},
    Publisher = {Sinodal'naja tip.},
    Title = {Sistematičeskoe opisanie rukopisej moskovskoj Sinodal'noj (patriaršej) biblioteki},
    Year = {1894}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            autolang=other,
            useprefix=true,
            giveninits=true,
            indexing=true,
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber,
        ]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=nomi] % texindy -L german-din5007 -C utf8 nomi.idx
\newcommand{\scindex}[2][]{\index[#1]{#2|textsc}}   %%%% Serve solo se voglio i numeri di pagina in smallcaps

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\ifnameundef{namea}{\indexnames{labelname}}{\indexnames{namea}}}
    {}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%      Formato del nome dell'autore
  \usebibmacro{index:name}
{\scindex[nomi]}%era    {\index[nomi]}. Così stampa le pagine in smallcaps
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}


\begin{document}


I should like to sort properly \cite{Dull} and \cite{Dol2}.



\printindex[nomi]       % Indice dei nomi   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Haven't tested, but don't run `xindy` on `name.idx`, run it on `nomi.idx`. Internally your index is called `nomi` and that is what the auxiliary files end up as.

Comment: Also don't run Biber on the `.aux`. Biber isn't BibTeX.

Comment: Edited, I was running nomi.idx, not name.idx as I wrote. It was a typo. About Biber, I get the same result either running biber on the .aux via texworks or running it via texshop on the main .tex with the "magic code" % !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber. In both cases the problem is still there, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Two things: Because of the way the index is produced it only makes sense to run `texindy` after a second XeLaTeX run. So I would use the order `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`, `xelatex`, `texindy`, `xelatex`, `xelatex` just to be sure of page references (in most cases you can probably get away with only one `xelatex` instead of two runs). Secondly, egreg's answer was not specifically for `xindy`. And apparently `xindy` needs to be told about `textsc`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58801/35864

Comment: I checked an `latex-loc-fmts.xdy` only knows `textbf`, `textit` and `hyperpage`. So you have to tell it about the `textsc` in your own `.xdy` file. Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270049/35864

Comment: Ok, let's make a xindy style with: (markup-locref :class "roman-page-numbers" :open  "\textsc{" :close "}")
I got a file mystyle.xdy. And now? I want to die, really.